# Unable to serve angular project on windows

Tags: node.js, bash, angular, npm

I am using node js, angular cli on windows environment, I recently cloned project I am working on to my windows machine, but its doesn't serves an gives the following erorr, where as the project runs perfectly on my linux machine, what can be the possible reason?

```
ng serve
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200 **
 12% building modules 22/38 modules 16 active ...tend\node_modules\strip-ansi\index.jsError: No module factory available for dependency type: ContextElementDependency
    at Compilation.addModuleDependencies (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:206:21)
    at Compilation.processModuleDependencies (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:195:8)
    at _this.buildModule.err (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:336:13)
    at building.forEach.cb (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:140:27)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at callback (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:140:13)
    at module.build (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:167:11)
    at resolveDependencies (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\ContextModule.js:133:4)
    at ContextModule.result.resolveDependencies (node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:229:25)
    at ContextModule.build (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\ContextModule.js:103:8)
    at Compilation.buildModule (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:142:10)
    at factoryCallback (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:325:11)
    at node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\ContextModuleFactory.js:96:12
    at node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:204:11
    at done.then (node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:231:28)
 13% building modules 27/43 modules 16 active ...lar\material\@angular\material.es5.js
node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:265
                                if(_this.profile) {
                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of null
    at factoryCallback (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:265:13)
    at factory (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:253:5)
    at applyPluginsAsyncWaterfall (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:99:14)
    at node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:204:11
    at NormalModuleFactory.params.normalModuleFactory.plugin (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\CompatibilityPlugin.js:52:5)
    at NormalModuleFactory.applyPluginsAsyncWaterfall (node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:208:13)
    at resolver (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:74:11)
    at process.nextTick (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:205:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

I also tried running ng serve via bash on ubuntu on windows it gave the following error

```
 npm start

> businessops@0.0.0 start 
> ng serve

EINVAL: invalid argument, uv_interface_addresses
Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, uv_interface_addresses
    at Error (native)
    at Object.lib.networkInterfaces (node_modules/macaddress/index.js:31:21)
    at Object.lib.one (node_modules/macaddress/index.js:79:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/uniqid/index.js:15:77)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/postcss-filter-plugins/dist/index.js:9:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)

npm ERR! Linux 3.4.0+
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! businessops@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the businessops@0.0.0 start script 'ng serve'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the businessops package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ng serve
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs businessops
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls businessops
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     npm-debug.log
```

Here is the contents of npm-debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs', '/usr/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v6.11.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle businessops@0.0.0~prestart: businessops@0.0.0
6 silly lifecycle businessops@0.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle businessops@0.0.0~start: businessops@0.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle businessops@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle businessops@0.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
10 verbose lifecycle businessops@0.0.0~start: CWD: 
11 silly lifecycle businessops@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'ng serve' ]
12 silly lifecycle businessops@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle businessops@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: businessops@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:255:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid businessops@0.0.0
16 verbose cwd /mnt/c/Users/saif/Documents/Angular/Businessops/frontend
17 error Linux 3.4.0+
18 error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
19 error node v6.11.1
20 error npm  v3.10.10
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error businessops@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the businessops@0.0.0 start script 'ng serve'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the businessops package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     ng serve
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs businessops
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls businessops
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: an error is there in  this line `if(_this.profile) {`. correct it or update the post with code

Comment: the thing is that's not in my my code, that error exists inside node_modules; webpack module.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  It is a known bug in WLS (see https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1343).

Here is the workaround: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1343#issuecomment-279781472

> ```
> // hack for Ubuntu on Windows
> try {
>   require('os').networkInterfaces();
> }
> catch (e) {
>   require('os').networkInterfaces = () => ({});
> }
> ```
>
> Place that code in a file and require it in webpack.config.js file.

In my case the error came from node_modules/macaddress/index.js and just adding this code at the start solve the problem.

It seems the issue is fixed in the latest Windows 10 version.